# DB2 query where first two digits of column are numeric

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in db2 with these values and columns.

```
part    location    quantity
456     09B4        500
456     94C7        850
456     73B1        700
567     38A5        945
879     MR43F       1241
651     DC234       456
654     C34         546
456     B342        756
567     73B1        800
```

I need a sql statement for db2 that would be do this.

```
SELECT quantity FROM tablename WHERE part = '456' 
AND ((first two digits of location are numeric) OR (location LIKE 'MR%')
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this in db2. I need all the rows where part number is '456' and the first two characters of location are numeric and also the rows that start with 'MR'

Comment: None of the rows you show meet that criteria.  Is that what you intended?  When you say `first two digits of location AND location like 'MR%'`  it would seem you mean a location that starts with 'MR' and has two digits anywhere else in the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think DB2 has built-in support for regular expressions.  But, you can do character by character comparisons:

```
SELECT quantity
FROM tablename
WHERE part = '456' AND
      ((left(location, 1) BETWEEN '0' and '9' AND
        substr(location, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' and '9'
       ) OR
       location LIKE 'MR%'
      )
```

Comment: Why not `substr(location, 1, 2) BETWEEN '00' and '99'`?

Comment: @JaugarChang . . . Because '2a' would match that condition.